# In Django is there a way to have context processors for only certain views?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want only certain views to pass through a processor.  For example, for about half of my views, I want to run a custom authentication method.  If the user isn't authenticated, it would redirect them to a new page.  Whats a good way to do something like this in Django?

Comment: To a register page? or just a normal page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A context processor isn't what you need for this. Context processors (like their name implies) inject extra context when rendering a template.

What you want is redirect before the view even runs (and therefore before any template is rendered).

This can be achieved with [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/), but middleware is more useful to apply to *all* your views.

In your case, you should write [a decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/decorators/), and decorate those views with it. Specifically, you probably want to use [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def my_auth_check(user):
    # Do something
    if all_good(user):
        return True
    return False

@user_passes_test(my_auth_check)
def my_view(request):
    # stuff

@user_passes_test(my_auth_check)
def my_other_view(request):
    # stuff
```